# Why doesn't request.GET.get capture this parameter?

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-templates

I am working on a Django application that has a central page with many links to several functions. To keep track of the links I have made a template: xtodo.html and its corresponding view: xtodo_view

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>En construcción</title>
</head>
<h1 align="left">EN CONSTRUCCIÓN</h1>

<h1>
   <h1>{{pagref}}</h1>
<div>
    <img src="http://{{ request.META.HTTP_HOST }}/static/logos/Under_construction_icon-orange.svg.png" width="300"
         height="250" alt="UnderConstruction"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the view

```
def xtodo_view(request):  # para pruebas, quitar
if request.method == 'GET':
    pagref = request.GET.get('pagref','g')
elif request.method == 'POST':
    pagref = request.POST.get('pagref','p')
return render(request, 'incid/xtodo.html', {'pagref': pagref})
```

whenever necessary, I code the calls this way:

```
<a href="{% url 'incid:xtodo' %}?pagref='newincidencia'" type="button"
               class="btn btn-primary waves-effect"> Nueva incidencia</a>
```

or

```
<li><a href=" {% url 'incid:xtodo' %}?pagref='perfil'"><i class="material-icons">person</i>Perfil</a>
                    </li>
```

With the hope that an "under construction" page will appear, indicating the name I have indicated for the link, but it works only for the first case - which is a button - but not in the others which are mere links.
What am I missing?.

Comment: There is a space before the `{% url ... }%`? Furthermore it is rather strange that you wrap it in quotes. Normally it should be `?pageref=prefil`, since the quote is an invalid URL character.

Comment: Adjusted all that, but the result is the same. Only works for the button. The request executes but gets nothing and returns the default value "g".